# Tracing Windows API calls over all processes

Tags: c#, python, windows, hook, trace

I am trying to write an application that will make statics over the usage of certain functions and DLLs of Windows API over **all the running processes** (as well as ones that are created after my application has started).

After searching the internet I have found several tools that may help - such as `WinAPIOverride`, `EasyHook` and `ProcMon`, which use different kind of hooks. Unfortunately, it seems for me that they are not able to make exactly what I need: `WinAPIOverride`, `EasyHook` can hook only certain processes that one should choose, and `ProcMon` doesn't have an interface that I can use to trace calls of API that I need.

I also wonder if this kind of hooking could interface with a Python code, or at least C# environment.

I would like to hear some suggestions for how this could be done.

Comment: There is a procmon hook, 2 secs

Comment: And how do I use it?

Answer (score 2):

This article may not be the holy grail for what you're trying to do but certainly will get you further in your quest:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2082/API-hooking-revealed

*I'm not 100% sure that is the article I was thinking of for tapping into ProcMon*.. After further research I'm pretty sure it was EasyHook I was thinking about: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27637/EasyHook-The-reinvention-of-Windows-API-hooking

Also ETW might be another avenue to investigate: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/570690/Application-Analysis-with-Event-Tracing-for-Window